# GalaSoft.MvvmLight Package reference error with .net Standard 2.0 project

Tags: .net, visual-studio, xamarin, nuget, .net-standard-2.0

Hi Stackoverflow community,

I am in the process of creating a .Net Standard 2.0 Library project for my Xamarin Cross Platform App.

For the Droid project which references the above project I am getting the following error for one of the NuGet packages:

```
Can not resolve reference: 'GalaSoft.MvvmLight', referenced by 'NetStdLibProject'. Please add a NuGet package or assembly reference for 'GalaSoft.MvvmLight', or remove the reference to 'NetStdLibProject'.    NetProject.Droid
```

I have added following NuGet Packages to my NetStdLibProject project:

1. MVVMLight (5.4.1.1)
2. MVVMLightLibs (5.4.1.1) [This has following warning]

(Package 'MvvmLightLibs 5.4.1.1' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.)

Please advise if there is a way to handle this scenario, or even if I am missing something.
Also, please let me know if I need to include other related/beneficial packages.

PS: Me and my colleagues use Visual Studio 2019 (Windows & Mac both, Mac for IOS part to be somewhat specific)

Thanks for reading and any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: a cursory glance at their webpage shows a .NET Standard version of the lib - https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmLightLibsStd10/

Comment: Hi @Jason,

Thanks for your response.

I added MVVMLightLibsStd10 to my NetStdLibProject  project.

This is how the references now look like:

MVVMLight (5.4.1.1)


MVVMLightLibsStd10 (5.4.1.1)

 -> GalaSoft.MvvmLight.dll.


This project builds correctly.
However, the Droid project is still giving the same reference error.

Comment: Hi @Jason,

I removed the .MVVMLight (5.4.1.1) reference as well, from my previous comment.

This is how the references now look like:

MVVMLightLibsStd10 (5.4.1.1)

 -> GalaSoft.MvvmLight.dll.


This project builds correctly.
However, the Droid project is still giving the same reference error.

Comment: See my updated answer, you have to install MVVMLightLibsStd10 for all the project in your solution.

Comment: Hi @JackHua-MSFT, Thanks for your response.

I added MVVMLightLibsStd10 to my Droid project as well, as per your recommendation. That caused this error: "Cannot find App.xaml file in this project, no other changes made. If you are installing in a PCL, please use 'MVVM Light Libs Only' instead."

Then I installed 'MVVMLightLibs'. Didn't help.

If I remove 'MVVMLightLibsStd10' reference, rebuild, I get many errors similar to:
"error: package com.google.android.gms.common.api does not exist
  com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback" for many similar .java files.

Comment: Did you remove MVVMLightLibs nuget package before install MVVMLightLibsStd10? The App.xaml file is in your PCL project. Try to clean and rebuild your solution again. I installed the MVVMLightLibsStd10 on my side and it all works well.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT, Yes i did remove all other MVVM related references. The only one present, in my NetStdLibProject is MVVMLightLibsStd10. However, the error in the post still persists.

Comment: Can you share me a Minimal, Reproducible Example so that I can test it on my side?

Answer (score 0):

As Jason suggested in the comment, you should install [MvvmLightLibsStd10](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmLightLibsStd10) for `.NET Standard`:

You should uninstall the `MvvmLightLibs` package and install `MvvmLightLibsStd10` **for all projects**(sharedPrject,Android.project,iOS.project).

Right click your **solution**(not single project) and choose `Manage Nuget Package for solution`.

see my updated screenshot:

[image]

Refer: [mvvmlight](http://www.mvvmlight.net/)